# What resources are available for learning QCL?

Tags: programming, resource-request, qcl

I'm struggling to find much about the language [QCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Computation_Language), rather than about quantum computing itself.

Is there anything out there like that? It doesn't have to be free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick googling reveals that [Bernhard Ömer](http://tph.tuwien.ac.at/~oemer/) has worked extensively on this topic. Check out the documentation section [here](http://tph.tuwien.ac.at/~oemer/qcl.html). He describes the installation procedure on the corresponding [GitHub page](https://github.com/aviggiano/qcl).

1. [Quantum Programming in QCL (PDF)](http://tph.tuwien.ac.at/~oemer/doc/quprog.pdf)

> My master thesis in computing science deals with computational and architectural questions of quantum programming and illustrates the design of quantum algorithms in QCL. For readers with a CS rather than a physical background, this book also features a brief introduction into quantum physics in general.

2. [A Procedural Formalism for Quantum Computing (PDF)](http://tph.tuwien.ac.at/~oemer/doc/qcldoc.pdf)

> My master thesis in theoretical physics about QCL. Besides a general introduction to quantum programming and a description of the language, a complete QCL implementation of the Shor algorithm is presented.

3. [Structured Quantum Programming (PDF)](http://tph.tuwien.ac.at/~oemer/doc/structquprog.pdf)

> My PhD thesis on structured programming languages for quantum computing (latest revision Jan 9 2009).

4. [Classical Concepts in Quantum Programming](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0211100)

> This paper from the QS2002 conference describes classical concepts in QCL, including new features like conditional operators, quantum conditions and quantum if-statements. The print version appeared in the International Journal of Theoretical Physics 44/7, pp. 943-955, 2005.

Also, check out these video lectures on QCL by [Macheads101](http://macheads101.com/pages/about.php):

- [Quantum Programming Tutorial #1: Installing QCL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rF2DDvGsYmY)
- [Quantum Programming Tutorial #2: Basic Qubit Operations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GO6TsdwxcwM)
- [Quantum Programming Tutorial #3: The V Gate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5rJ78_U_go)

Comment: Thanks, I had already found all of this (as you said, a quick google), but I assume since nothing else popped up for answers there just isn't much else out there. I was hoping for something like a textbook that more widely used programming languages have. The Macheads videos would be good, but he stopped making them after just three simple videos. I'm sure Omer's work is great but it seems to assume quite a bit of prior knowledge.